# Program constantly crashes requiring an argument count of at least 3

Tags: c

Im suppose to write a program that validates CLI command. My program sort of works when there are two parameters but when i add the third, it crashes. I've been stuck for hours.Your help will be greatly appreciated! :D

[image: Commands]

**This is what im supposed to do.**
Instructor recommended me to break my solution into 3 functions:

- validate command: this function takes the command line arguments and
  validates that they represent a valid command for the system. Return a Boolean
  indicating if the command was valid or not.
- print help: this function prints a complete usage (help) message for the user
- main: the main function uses the above to validate the command, and then
  perform an n-way branch or switch to select the correct option and print a
  suitable message.

Ive put a comment block in the validArgue function trying to isolate and debug it

**Heres my code**

```
/*
 * Assignment 2 Encryption part 1
 * Author : Brian HO
 * Date: 12/02/2018
 *
 */

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #include <string.h>

 bool validArgue(char* input, int length,char* string);
 bool helpManual(char* input);

     int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char* input = argv[1];
    int length = atoi(argv[2]);
    char* string = argv[2];

    if(helpManual(input)) {
        printf("\nUsage:   encrypt -k 123\n   or:   encrypt -f textfile.txt\n   or:   enctypt -e/d textfile.txt keyfile.txt\n\n\tOptions:\n\t\t-h\t\t\tPrint this help manual.\n\t\t-k <length>\t\tGenerate encryption key for given length (length > 0).\n\t\t-f <filename>\t\tGenerate frequency histogram for filename.\n\t\t-e <filename> <keyfile> Encrypt cleartxt in filename with given keyfile.\n\t\t-d <filename> <keyfile> Decipher ciphertext filename with given keyfile.\n\n");
    }
    if(validArgue(input,length,string)){
        printf("Command is valid!");
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid arguments...\n\nUsage:   encrypt -k 123\n   or:   e 
    ncrypt -f textfile.txt\n   or:   enctypt -e/d textfile.txt 
    keyfile.txt\n\n\tOptions:\n\t\t-h\t\t\tPrint this help manual.\n\t\t-k 
    <length>\t\tGenerate encryption key for given length (length > 0).\n\t\t-f 
    <filename>\t\tGenerate frequency histogram for filename.\n\t\t-e <filename> 
    <keyfile> Encrypt cleartxt in filename with given keyfile.\n\t\t-d 
    <filename> <keyfile> Decipher ciphertext filename with given keyfile.");
    }
    return 0;
}


bool helpManual(char* input) {
    char ch1 = input[0];


    char ch2 = input[1];
    if(ch1 == '-' && ch2 == 'h'){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
     }
 }

bool validArgue(char* input, int length, char* string){
    char ch = string[1];
    if (strcmp(input, "-h")==0){
        return true;
    }
    else if (strcmp(input, "-k")==0) {
        if (length >0) {
            return true;
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
    else if (strcmp(input, "-f")==0) {
        if (ch>0) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
      else 
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `argv[i]` before you have checked that `argv > i`. For example if no arguments are provided then `argv[1]` will be a null pointer, and `argv[2]` will be out of bounds. If one argument is provided then `argv[2]` will be a null pointer. Think about what happens with the `atoi` call if `argv[2]` is out of bounds or a null pointer.

Comment: Rather than returning a `bool` from your `validate()`, instead return an `int` representing which case the inputs satisfy and then `switch` on the return using the `default` case for your *invalid input* case. (**note you can break your string literals `"I need to print this long stuff"` into separate lines `"I need "` then `"to print "` and `"this long stuff"` to make your code much more readable. C ignores the newlines.

Comment: Also, if `helpManual` returns `true`, then you should probably not let the program continue, like you do now.

Comment: Thankyou so much guys. Let me try your suggestions and solutions and i shall get back to you guys. You're the best guys! and shout out to C_elegans and Ken White for edits